# how to set range for up and down camera mouvment

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, rotation, orthographic

I am making a game with an orthographic camera, the camera suppose to turn around the player and move up and down on mouse hold. The problem is that I can't find a way to make a range for the up and down movement, it is only supposed to go up and down for just a small angle
this is my code

```
void LateUpdate () {

if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{

    RotateAroundPlayer = true;


}
else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
{
    RotateAroundPlayer = false;
}

if (RotateAroundPlayer)
{
    Quaternion camTurnAngle =
        Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * RotationsSpeed, Vector3.up);
    Quaternion camUpDown =
        Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * RotationsSpeed, transform.right);
   
    _cameraOffset = camUpDown * camTurnAngle * _cameraOffset;
    
}
Vector3 newPos = PlayerTransform.position + _cameraOffset;
transform.position = Vector3.Slerp(transform.position, newPos, SmoothFactor);

if (LookAtPlayer || RotateAroundPlayer)
    transform.LookAt(PlayerTransform);
```

}

I tried to add the code below but the camera win it reaches the minimum value it goes a way

```
    _cameraOffset.y = Mathf.Clamp(_cameraOffset.y,  minViewingAngle,maxViewingAngle);
```

Comment: What about using `Math.Max` and `Math.Min` instead of `Mathf`? See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math?view=net-6.0

Comment: Where did you try to add the `Mathf.Clamp` line?

Comment: @Ibrennan208 same result, it did not work. I tried to added Mathf.Clamp  before and after     `_cameraOffset = camUpDown * camTurnAngle * _cameraOffset;`